# kubernetes pods/pod/exec API call 403 forbidden response

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have an init-container in my deployment definition with a shared volume and a directory '/validators'. Inside this directory, there is a sh file that I want to execute using the following URL [http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/env-654b4aa0e8ab6dd24f7a33e4-6542b780436645c47c706759-6c8cpvqxk/exec?container=init-container&command=/bin/bash&command=-c&command=bash%20/validators/step_1.sh](https://stackoverflow.com) However, upon launching, I receive a 403 'forbidden' response, even though I have granted all permissions to my service account. Note that it works as expected when I use 'kubectl' to execute the file."

my role definition

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: full-access-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

role binding def

```
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: full-access-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elyes
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: full-access-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I tried with the definitions above, yet I only got 403 responses. I appreciate your help